# nuget credentials how to tell which provider is being used?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, nuget

So for "security" reasons I am forced to use a different account to run visual studio for certain admin level operations (registering COM objects mostly). TFS however only knows about my lower level regular account. In the past this hasn't been an issue and I've set credentials up for my admin account to log into TFS with the regular account.

However something has changed since I last did a password change and logging into one particular nuget feed (hosted by TFS / Azure devops server in house) from VS2019 running as admin will lock my AD account. Also my git TFS account seems not to be using the correct account. A different feed hosted by the same TFS instance (the only difference is the feed name) works fine.

I have tried setting credentials for nuget using `dotnet nuget update source name -u username -p password` and that hasn't helped. I suspect since git gives issues when I push to the TFS server it's using some sort of windows stored user name and password and nuget is using the same invalid credentials. I can login to TFS to search for work items in VS2019 to add on git commits so at least one provider is set correctly.

So my question is how do I find out what the actual username and credential type / provider is being used for a particular nuget feed? Ideally I'd like to find out what username it's using as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please first make sure the account you were logging in with do have permission to the nuget package.

`how do I find out what the actual username and credential type / provider is being used for a particular nuget feed?`

You should find CredentialProvider in my local folder:

`C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\NuGet\CredentialProviders\`

[**Use NuGet with Azure DevOps Services feeds**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/nuget-exe?view=azure-devops)

Also give a try with below solution, check if this do the trick:

1. Right click on your solution from Solution Explorer
2. Manage Nuget Packages for Solution-> on top right corner click on the gear symbol -> on the left hand-side go to NuGet Package Manager
3. Package Sources -> on right hand-side UNCHECKED the package source you are having trouble with
4. Click Ok button -> restart your VS it should only ask you login once
   now

.

Comment: Hmm I don't actually have anything in the credentials providers folder for either user. The problem is in part that the user running Visual Studio doesn't have access to the feed, I need to use my regular account for access (blame infosec for this). Back with more when I can. Going to have a quick look at the credential provider source code to see it looks likely installing it will fix my issues.

Comment: Feeds have four levels of access: Owners, Contributors, Collaborators, and Readers. Owners can add any type of identity-individuals, teams, and groups-to any access level. You could add that user to Contributor role. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops

Comment: `Going to have a quick look at the credential provider source code to see it looks likely installing it will fix my issues.` Feel free to update any result here.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that my admin level user account is using an old password to log into the nuget repo so I need to figure where it's pulling the credentials from so I can change them. The real pain point is that browsing a repo will lock the account in AD so I then need to talk to my IT dept to unlock the account. I'm pretty sure I've changed all the stuff in "rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr" I'll come back with whatever I find later on.

Answer (score 1):

Okay in my case it turns out different versions of nuget are in use.
The CredentialProviders folder was empty.

However I suspect an older version of nuget was involved that looks in this config file
`C:\Users\<your_account>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config` which in my case had the same repository name twice with slightly different casing (no idea why?) and the password was incorrect on one of those entries (they should all be the same).

So running `nuget.exe sources update` for the older mechanism as well as `dotnet nuget update source` worked. I also notice that `update source` requires a later version of the dotnet sdk than I happened to have specified in `global.json` for this project.

So I suspect this is mostly down to having

- multiple versions of nuget on my machine along with a somewhat elderly dotnet sdk being in use.
- The nuget repository having the same name only differing in case

I hope this helps someone else at some point.

I have marked Patrick Lu answer as correct as it actually answers my original question.